# What does Islam think is the problem with atheism?

Tags: belief, atheists, atheism

All other religions such as Christianity are believed to have their books altered (as we believe in Islam) and other religions such as Hinduism are seen as false due to the ideas of demi god. However, atheism hasnt really been addressed in the Quran or hadith because the prophet didnt encounter atheists. What does Islam think is the problem with atheism?

Edit:If clarification is needed for this question please ask. By what is wrong I meant part of the reason we arent christians or hindus is because there are flaws with those religions which is why we go to Islam.

Comment: Atheism is kufr denial of Allah and His orders,The quràn actually quote them and the sunnah too.

Comment: The problem with atheism is pretty obvious: they deny Allah's existence. What exactly are you looking for in this question?

Comment: No like I know they deny Allahs existence but we see flaws in other religions themselves which is partly why we accept this religion and not others. What are the flaws with atheism (flaws that we believe as Muslims)?

Comment: @Medi1Saif Not all atheist deny god's existence. They only doubt ( doubt neither means denial not acceptance) due to lack of logics (according to them ).

Answer (score 2):

The "flaw" in atheism, according to Islam, is that they believe in things that are not true, such as the idea that Allah does not exist, or that Muhammad was not His messenger, or that the Qur'an is not His message. Believing in things that are not true — while simultaneously not believing in things that *are* true — is a pretty flimsy basis for any belief system.

Comment: Can you give an example of the things they believe that arent true? Also it is impossible to know whether the Quran or god really is true so its not necessarily a flaw and to compensate there are theories (really well researched explained and developed) that compensate for their ideas that there is no god.

Answer (score 0):

Islam is a monolithic set of rules which denies any other way of life (diversity) which exists in nature. In summation, if one rejects the "Allah" (Islamic God), reject Muhammad ibn Abdullāh's "claim of being his messenger" and Quran is disbeliever and subject to some kind of punishments.

Atheism is one of the form of diversity or way of life which exist in nature and it rejects any claims made by Islam or any Semitic religions. So if you go rejects their claims you would be tagged with other tags like you are doing kufr ( which is again defined in Islam only).

Answer (score 0):

Atheism means a creator does not exists. While Islam is clearly established by the acceptance of God's existence and that he is Allah (swt). So if those other religions that accept the existence of a Creator are false, by greater reason rejecting his existence is of greater falsehood since the members of other religions can be convinced the correct concept of the creator is the Islamic one. Whereas atheists complicate simple matters by making outrageous arguments - [Can atheists proof God does not exists?](https://www.islamiqate.com/3444/can-atheists-refute-arguments-proofs-for-the-existence-god)

Hence, the atheists reject the existence of a creator, whereas the other religions accept a deity exist(s) - even if some of them accept multiple Gods. This does not mean they are lesser in crime since in Islam only the chosen Deen of Muhammad (saw) is true. Any other belief and disbelief are false. Hope this answers your question.